# How to create a new profile for Google Chrome?

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, user-profiles, ubuntu-10.10

How can I set two or more Chrome profiles in Ubuntu 10.10 ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer here: [Multiple profiles in Google Chrome](http://techspalace.blogspot.com/2010/02/multiple-profile-in-google-chrome-in.html)

Comment: your link is spammy/vague...I would delete, except this is an answer to your own post.  Be careful!

Comment: however this was what I needed, and it work for me

Comment: It'd be better to actually answer the problem here with the steps you took and then link to your blog.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to SET different chrome profiles in the ubuntu quicklist, I think that this is the best solution, it works for me:

Run the commands:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop
```

add the following codes:

```
X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Work;Personal;Three

[Work Shortcut Group]
Name=New Work Profile window
Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --enable-udd-profiles --user-data-dir=.config/google-chrome/Work %U
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[Personal Shortcut Group]
Name=New Personal Profile window
Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --enable-udd-profiles --user-data-dir=.config/google-chrome/Personal %U
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[Three Shortcut Group]
Name=New Third Profile window
Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --enable-udd-profiles --user-data-dir=.config/google-chrome/Third %U
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[No Security Shorcut]
Name=Touch no web security Profile
Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --enable-udd-profiles --user-data-dir=.config/google-chrome/Third --disable-web-security --touch-events %U
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

Save and close the file. Restart Unity

```
unity --replace
```

Source:
[http://www.tendogs.net/](http://www.tendogs.net/home/how-to/add-multiple-chrome-profiles-to-a-unity-quick-list-in-unbunty)